# Help with Help Lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am plotting lattice paths to two points. I would like to have help lines drawn on top of the Cartesian plane so that any line that is an integral distance from an axis is a solid line and any line that is an odd integral multiple of 0.5 from an axis is dashed.  The help lines that I have are not even consistent with the axes!

How to I get the `O`, `A`, and `B` typeset over the help lines.  The option `[fill=white,circle,inner sep=0pt]` is ignored in my code. So, one of the (misplaced) help lines is drawn over it.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning}



\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=-11,xmax=11,ymin=-11,ymax=11,
    axis lines=middle,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
        ]

\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\node[fill=white,circle,inner sep=0pt] (O-label) at ($(O)+(-135:10pt)$) {$O$};
\coordinate (A) at (-2.5,9.5);
\node[fill=white,circle] (A-label) at ($(A)+(-180:10pt)$) {$A$};
\coordinate (B) at (7,-3.5);
\node[fill=white,circle] (B-label) at ($(B)+(-45:10pt)$) {$B$};

\draw[fill] (O) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (A) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (B) circle (1.5pt);

%These commands are for drawing a path from O to A.
\coordinate (A1) at (-0.5,0);
\coordinate (A2) at (-.5,3);
\coordinate (A3) at (-2.5,3);

\draw[line width=1pt] (O) -- (A1) -- (A2) -- (A3) -- (A);

%These commands are for drawing a path from O to B.
\coordinate (B1) at (2,0);
\coordinate (B2) at (2,-2.5);
\coordinate (B3) at (5,-2.5);
\coordinate (B4) at (5,-3.5);
\coordinate (B) at (7,-3.5);

\draw[line width=1pt] (O) -- (B1) -- (B2) -- (B3) -- (B4) -- (B);

\draw[help lines,line width=0.1pt,blue] (-10.5, -10.5) grid (10.5,10.5);


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}
\vskip0.25in

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your points need to be given as `(axis cs:x,y)` or you need to upgrade to version 1.12 and explicitly put `compat=1.12`. Then it will automatically assume axis coordinates.

Comment: @percusse  Thanks.  I can add `axis cs:` to the points.  How do I upgrade to version 1.12?  I am looking at page 12 of the manual at `http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf`.  It says that "Windows users often use MikTEX which downloads the latest stable package versions automatically. You do not need to install anything manually here."  I am using WinEdt 8.1.

Comment: In your MikTeX start menu options there is an item `Upgrad (admin)` or something like that. If you select that it will search and show you the updatable packages . See this one http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution

Comment: @percusse  I am using WinEdt.

Comment: WinEdt is your editor where you type your document. It uses a TeX distribution which is MikTeX or TeX Live. Windows users usually use MikTeX. Look at your start menu you should see it there. Then follow the instructions.

Comment: @percusse  OK.  (I haven't heard of "Tex distribution," and I don't know much about programming.)  I am looking at "Installation on Windows" on page 12.  It says that "MikTeX downloads the latest stable package versions automatically."  I changed `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}` to `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}` in the preamble and tried to compile it.  I got errors.

Comment: Look at your start menu. You **have to** find your distribution and I'm sure it is MikTeX. You need to find and do the update with it. WinEdt will not update anything.

Comment: @percusse  I went to "Programs" in the start menu and selected `MikTeX2.7`.   A menu appeared.  I selected "Update."  Another menu appeared.  I selected "I want to get updated packages from a remote package repository" and "Use the nearest package repository."  I select "Next" and I get the error "The operation could not be completed because MikTeX is not supported anymore."  What should I do to update to MikTeX2.9?

Comment: Oh yes. Definitely. Uninstall that and then install 2.9

Answer (score 7):

<sup>This is also an answer to the [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246872/positioning-a-node-via-using-tikz-to-calculate-arctan2/246875?noredirect=1#comment587118_246875) for another [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/246875/16967) of another [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246872/16967).</sup>

To get help lines overprinted, they have to be printed first below the following objects. The `\draw` command should be placed before the other elements.

The next problem are the misplaced lines. The following command adds the grid lines at least in the area (-10, -10) to (10, 10):

```
\draw[
  help lines,
  line width=0.1pt,
  blue,
  shift={($(1, 1) - (0, 0)$)},
] (-11, -11) grid[step={($(5, 5) - (0, 0)$)}] (9, 9);
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}   
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=-11,xmax=11,ymin=-11,ymax=11,
    axis lines=middle,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
        ]

\draw[
  help lines,
  line width=0.1pt,
  blue,
  shift={($(1, 1) - (0, 0)$)},
] (-11, -11) grid[step={($(5, 5) - (0, 0)$)}] (9, 9);

\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\node[fill=white,circle,inner sep=0pt] (O-label) at ($(O)+(-135:10pt)$) {$O$};
\coordinate (A) at (-2.5,9.5);
\node[fill=white,circle] (A-label) at ($(A)+(-180:10pt)$) {$A$};
\coordinate (B) at (7,-3.5);
\node[fill=white,circle] (B-label) at ($(B)+(-45:10pt)$) {$B$};

\draw[fill] (O) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (A) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (B) circle (1.5pt);

%These commands are for drawing a path from O to A.
\coordinate (A1) at (-0.5,0);
\coordinate (A2) at (-.5,3); 
\coordinate (A3) at (-2.5,3);

\draw[line width=1pt] (O) -- (A1) -- (A2) -- (A3) -- (A);

%These commands are for drawing a path from O to B.
\coordinate (B1) at (2,0);   
\coordinate (B2) at (2,-2.5);
\coordinate (B3) at (5,-2.5);
\coordinate (B4) at (5,-3.5);
\coordinate (B) at (7,-3.5);

\draw[line width=1pt] (O) -- (B1) -- (B2) -- (B3) -- (B4) -- (B);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The full plot area from -11 to 11 in both directions can be covered by:

```
\begin{scope}
  \clip (-11, -11) rectangle (11, 11);
  \draw[
    help lines,
    line width=0.1pt,
    blue,
    shift={($(1, 1) - (0, 0)$)},
  ] (-16, -16) grid[step={($(5, 5) - (0, 0)$)}] (10, 10);
\end{scope}
```

However, the axis tick labels are overwritten by the help lines. Therefore I would rather use the `grid` option of the `axis` environment:

```
\begin{axis}[
  ...,
  grid,
  grid options={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!30},
]
  ...
\end{axis}
```

> [image: Result grid option]

Comment: Your display is nice.  I have seen that there is a `canvas coordinate system` and an `axis coordinate system`, and they are not the same.  I think the command `shift={($(1, 1) - (0, 0)$)},` is relevant to the different coordinate systems.  Please explain this command.

Comment: @user74973 The origins of the coordinate systems are different. Especially the origin of the `axis coordinate system` is not at `(0pt, 0pt)`. Therefore I use the difference to calculate the step width.

Comment: I do not know how `shift={($(1, 1) - (0, 0)$)}` compensates for this.  Can you offer a link at which I can read about this?

Comment: In this case, I agree with you that  the `grid` option of the `axis` environment is appropriate so that the lines from the grid are not drawn over the tick labels.  I am not sure of the syntax.  Here is my guess.  `(-10.5,-10.5) grid[xstep=1, ystep=1]  (10.5,10.5)`.  I would like to have `line width=0.1pt,` and `draw=gray!30`.

Comment: @user74973 The plot area starts at `(-11, -11)`, but I want to start the grid at a multiply of the grid step width, `(-10, -10)`. Since the origin of the axis coordinate system is in `(0, 0)` or eleven x units to the right and eleven y units to the top I can't use `shift={(1, 1)}`, I have to use the difference. Documentation, see [`pgf` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) and [`pgfplots` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf). The latter explains the configuration of `grid` in section "4.16 Grid Options" .

Comment: I just looked at the `pgfplots manual` for the grid options.  This "section"  is less than a page!  I will post a request for help in drawing a grid using the axis options.